# Re-render Vue instance after jquery add a html node

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a legacy project in SAP Hybris framework, mixed with VueJS and JSP files with jQuery to deal, and I need to add the following feature:

My JSP File use the following jquery structure to replace a part of content in HTML.

```
$('.loadItems').load('/cart .loadItems', function (response, status, xhr) {
  ACC.cartitem.bindCartItem() // they only bind all classes with 'click' eventListener again             
})
```

The file JSP with the .loadItems class

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="cartData" required="true" type="de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.data.CartData" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="product" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/product" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="storepickup" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/storepickup" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="cart" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/responsive/cart" %>

<spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape="true" />

<c:set var="errorStatus" value="<%= de.hybris.platform.catalog.enums.ProductInfoStatus.valueOf(\"ERROR\") %>" />
<div class="loadItems">
<ul class="item__list item__list__cart">
    <c:forEach items="${cartData.rootGroups}" var="group" varStatus="loop">
        <cart:rootEntryGroup cartData="${cartData}" entryGroup="${group}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
</div>

<product:productOrderFormJQueryTemplates />
<storepickup:pickupStorePopup />
```

I know, this is not the best way to replace part of html structure, but I dont have a endpoint API to load the response by JSON at this moment.

But on this cart items I have a modal in VueJS.
When this cart items are loaded and replaced and re-render the DOM, I loss the VueJS instance.

My VueJS instance structure is this:

```
<div id="#app">
  {{ all my template with if/else and vars }}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   props: [... my props ...],
   methods: { ...my methods... }
  })
 })
</script>
```

Idk if I'm clear on my question, but thanks for your time trying to help me.

Comment: can you post the entire code, where `.loadItems` element is present?

Comment: of course, I will update my content